# Fixing a function to find and remove outliers from the dataset

Tags: r, function, outliers

I am trying to make a simple function which will find and remove outliers automatically. This is the function I have created so far:

```
fOutlier <- function(x, y) {
     outlier <- with(x, boxplot.stats(y)$out)
     subset(x, !(y %in% outlier))
}
data <- fOutlier(data, variable)
```

The problem is that the function does not read x as dataset name. It works if I use the following:

```
data <- fOutlier(data, data$variable)
```

Comment: `subset` and `with` use non-standard evaluation. Great for interactive use, potentially problematic in functions see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#nse-downsides Use `boxplot(x[[y]])`. But automatic outlier removal is probably a bad idea

Comment: thanks. I'am aware that removing outliers without checking the data is not recommended, but I am doing this function for learning purposes. this `boxplot(x[[y]])` doesn't work!

Comment: That code was expecting y to be the column name as a string (or an integer giving the column number)

Comment: `y` is the column name (variable name). When i give the number of column still doesn't work. `with` is not the correct function inside the function. i have to think for other alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset) seems to be the culprit.

This is what I would personally do.

```
set.seed(1)

# mock data set
d<-data.frame(var1=rnorm(1000,500,50), 
              var2=rnorm(1000,1000,100),
              var3=rnorm(1000,1000,100), 
              var4=rnorm(1000,1000,100))

fOutlier<-function(dat, var_name){
  var_vec<-dat[,var_name]
  outliers<-boxplot.stats(var_vec)$out
  clean_dat<-dat[!(var_vec %in% outliers),]
}

# test with different variables
d_var1_clean<-fOutlier(d, 'var1')
d_var2_clean<-fOutlier(d, 'var2')
d_var3_clean<-fOutlier(d, 'var3')
```

If you really like the non-standard evaluation, then you can add eval() and substitute() to maintain this functionality.

This function is a workable version of what you posted (note the creation of y_vec):

```
fOutlier2 <- function(x, y) {  
  y_vec<-eval(substitute(y),eval(x))
  outlier <- boxplot.stats(y_vec)$out
  subset(x, !(y_vec %in% outlier))
}
d_var1_clean2<-fOutlier2(d, var1)
```